# If, Else statement trouble (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement

I am having problem displaying some text and opening a new class. I can only seem to do one, but not both, otherwise I get an error at the Else saying 'else without if'. I have to // either the println or app.loginOption, as i cannot have both without an error occuring. Thanks for any help

```
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT username, password from register WHERE username ='" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'");
        if(rs.next())
            Apps.loginOptions();
            //System.out.println("Login successful! " );

        else
            System.out.println("Username or login not found. Please try again: ");
```

Comment: You need to make your if a block with `{}`, without that, if only take one line in it.

Comment: This is Java. Not Python...

Answer (score 0):

Put both statement inside a parenthesis :

```
if(rs.next()) {
            Apps.loginOptions();
            System.out.println("Login successful! " );

         }
  else
     System.out.println("Username or login not found. Please try again: ");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now

Answer (score 0):

When compiled, your code is equivalent to:

```
if(rs.next()) {
                Apps.loginOptions();
}
//System.out.println("Login successful! " );
else {
    System.out.println("Username or login not found. Please try again:");
}
```

What you want is:

```
if(rs.next()) {
    Apps.loginOptions();
    //System.out.println("Login successful! " );
} else {
    System.out.println("Username or login not found. Please try again:");
}
```